# Instant access to newly created subdomain

Tags: apache, dns, nameservers, propagation, directadmin

I want to create new directadmin user with subdomain using da api and i need instant access to that newly created website.

Problem is that sometimes dns propagation takes to much time. 
I'm thinking about using domain wildcard along with storing copy of that website on my account until propagation ends.

Is there a better way to achieve that without duplicating that website?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your host file with the your domain name and new IP. A hosts file can be edited to override your network settings and thus allow your local machine to view a website prior to the DNS changes propagating.

```
123.45.67.89 www.example.com
```